# summaries by 2 categories using dplyr

Tags: r

Not sure what wrong I am doing here. I am trying to summarise the values and take column percentage using dplyr function. But the output is not as expected

```
asd <- data.frame(cat1 = c("A","B","A"), cat2 = c("A1","B1", "A1"), c = c(1,2,3))
asd %>% group_by(cat1, cat2) %>% summarise(total = n()) %>%  mutate(percent = round((total * 100 /sum(total)),1))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cat1'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   cat1 [2]
  cat1  cat2  total percent
  <chr> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
1 A     A1        2     100
2 B     B1        1     100
```

Expected output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   cat1 [2]
  cat1  cat2  total percent
  <chr> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
1 A     A1        2     66
2 B     B1        1     33
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the way you put the parentheses

Comment: Not sure what is wrong here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work, `count` is shortcut to `group_by` and `summarize n()`:

```
library(dplyr)
count(asd, cat1, cat2, name = 'total') %>% mutate(percent = round(total/sum(total)*100))
  cat1 cat2 total percent
1    A   A1     2      67
2    B   B1     1      33
```